# How to prove elimination rules using Isar?

Tags: isabelle

Here is a simple theory:

```
datatype t1 = A | B | C
datatype t2 = D | E t1 | F | G

inductive R where
  "R A B"
| "R B C"

inductive_cases [elim]: "R x B" "R x A" "R x C"

inductive S where
  "S D (E _)"
| "R x y ⟹ S (E x) (E y)"

inductive_cases [elim]: "S x D" "S x (E y)"
```

I can prove lemma `elim` using two helper lemmas:

```
lemma tranclp_S_x_E:
  "S⇧+⇧+ x (E y) ⟹ x = D ∨ (∃z. x = E z)"
  by (induct rule: converse_tranclp_induct; auto)

(* Let's assume that it's proven *)
lemma reflect_tranclp_E:
  "S⇧+⇧+ (E x) (E y) ⟹ R⇧+⇧+ x y"
  sorry

lemma elim:
  "S⇧+⇧+ x (E y) ⟹
   (x = D ⟹ P) ⟹ (⋀z. x = E z ⟹ R⇧+⇧+ z y ⟹ P) ⟹ P"
  using reflect_tranclp_E tranclp_S_x_E by blast
```

I need to prove `elim` using Isar:

```
lemma elim:
  assumes "S⇧+⇧+ x (E y)"
    shows "(x = D ⟹ P) ⟹ (⋀z. x = E z ⟹ R⇧+⇧+ z y ⟹ P) ⟹ P"
proof -
  assume "S⇧+⇧+ x (E y)"
  then obtain z where "x = D ∨ x = E z"
    by (induct rule: converse_tranclp_induct; auto)
  also have "S⇧+⇧+ (E z) (E y) ⟹ R⇧+⇧+ z y"
    sorry
  finally show ?thesis
```

But I get the following errors:

```
No matching trans rules for calculation:
    x = D ∨ x = E z
    S⇧+⇧+ (E z) (E y) ⟹ R⇧+⇧+ z y

Failed to refine any pending goal 
Local statement fails to refine any pending goal
Failed attempt to solve goal by exported rule:
  (S⇧+⇧+ x (E y)) ⟹ P
```

How to fix them?

I guess that this lemma could have a simpler proof. But I need to prove it in two steps:

1. Show the possible values of `x`
2. Show that `E` reflects transitive closure

I think also that this lemma could be proven by cases on `x`. But my real data types have too many cases. So, it's not a preferred solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variant seems to work:

```
lemma elim:
  assumes "S⇧+⇧+ x (E y)"
      and "x = D ⟹ P"
      and "⋀z. x = E z ⟹ R⇧+⇧+ z y ⟹ P"
    shows "P"
proof -
  have "S⇧+⇧+ x (E y)" by (simp add: assms(1))
  then obtain z where "x = D ∨ x = E z"
    by (induct rule: converse_tranclp_induct; auto)
  moreover
  have "S⇧+⇧+ (E z) (E y) ⟹ R⇧+⇧+ z y"
    sorry
  ultimately show ?thesis
    using assms by auto
qed
```

- Assumptions should be separated from the goal.
- As a first statement I shoud use `have` instead of `assume`. It's not a new assumption, just the existing one.
- Instead of `finally` I should use `ultimately`. It seems that the later one has a simpler application logic.

Comment: `also`/`finally` are for chaining transitive things together; e.g. `have "A = B", also have "B = C", finally have "A = C"`. If you only want to collect several facts and then use them all to show some final result, use `moreover`/`ultimately`. The error message you got indicated that `also`/`finally` could not find anything transitive in your goal statements to chain together.